# Cannot get local file from XMLHttpRequest

Tags: javascript, ajax, asynchronous, xmlhttprequest, http-status-code-404

Im trying to get an local txt file from calling a XMLHttpsRequest() method. But it keeps sending me a 404 error message in the console. Please help me out.

here is my html file

```
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Ajax1</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <button id="button" type="button" name="button">Get text files</button>

    <script type="text/javascript">
      document.getElementById("button").addEventListener('click', loadText)

      function loadText(){
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

        xhr.open('GET', 'sample.txt', true);

        xhr.onload = function(){
          if(xhr.status === 200){
            console.log(xhr.responseText)
          }
        }

        xhr.send(null);
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Local txt file is not inside any folder.
I dont know whether this is important or not but here is my app.js file

```
const express = require('express')

const app =express()
app.use(express.static("public"))

app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.sendFile(__dirname+'/ajax1.html')
})

app.listen(3000, function(){
  console.log('server is runing')
})
```

Comment: "Local txt file is not inside any folder" so the 404 is correct. It's not clear what you want.

Comment: Can you post your directory tree? Without knowing where the file is, and reading your question, it really seems the code is correct and there is no file.